# Why Realm doesn't find object which I inserted in transaction before?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, rx-java2, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement a simple chat application on web sockets in Clean Architecture. I had to choose a db for caching all information, so I decided to use Realm, because I heard it was pretty good database for any kind of mobile applications. But when I actually faced the Realm, it turned out to be really painful experience for me to implement caching logic with it.

All problems come from applying transaction to database which then must be synced on all threads working with Realm. There seems to some kind of synchronization problem with my code. For example, I want to save my object to Realm and then query it out of.

Here I have two simple functions to save and to get chat:

```
fun getBackgroundLooper(): Looper {
    val handlerThread = HandlerThread("backgroundThread")
    if (!handlerThread.isAlive)
         handlerThread.start()
    return handlerThread.looper
}

fun saveChat(chat: Chat): Completable {
    val realmChat = ChatMapper.domainToCache(chat)
    return Completable.create { e ->
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        realm.executeTransactionAsync({
            it.insertOrUpdate(realmChat)
        }, {
            realm.close()
            e.onComplete()
        }, {
            realm.close()
            e.onError(it)
        })
    // Subscribe on background looper thread 
    // to be able to execute async transaction
    }.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(getBackgroundLooper())) 
}

fun getSingleChat(chatId: String): Single<Chat> {
    return Single.defer {
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        realm.isAutoRefresh = true
        val realmChat = realm.where(RealmChat::class.java)
            .equalTo("id", chatId).findFirstAsync()

        if (realmChat.isValid) {
            realmChat.load()
            val chat = ChatMapper.cacheToDomain(realmChat)
            realm.close()
            Single.just(chat)
        }

        realm.close()
        Single.error<Chat>(ChatNotExistException())
    // Subscribe on background looper thread
    // to be able to execute auto refreshing
    }.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(getBackgroundLooper())) 
}
```

So, when I try to run simple code like this

```
remote.getChat().flatMap {
    cache.saveChat(it)   //save chat to realm
    .andThen(cache.getSingleChat(it.id))  //then query it by id
}
```

I always get no matter of what `ChatNotExistException`, but if I try to run query again in another attempt or after restarting the application, then the chat object gets found

I also tried many different approaches to execute this code:

- I tried to use `realm.refresh()` in `getSingleChat` or not use it at all.
- I tried to query chat synchronously with `findFirst()` and `findAll()` instead of `findFirstAsync()`.
- I tried querying chat on current thread without `.subscribeOn()`.
- I tried to use `realm.executeTransaction()` instead of async transactions.
- I tried to add thread sleep between saving and querying, so that transaction may take some time to get applied and I need to wait before attempting to query the chat

I'm begging anybody to explain me what am I doing wrong and how to make this code working. I can't change the architecture of my application and use Realm objects as my view models, I need to find solution in these conditions.

Comment: Have you tried with sync transaction and not async ?

Comment: @Maelig yes, of course I tried to use sync transactions. I made a function to execute sync transactions https://www.codepile.net/pile/MYe4361q.
It also did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I actually faced the Realm, it turned out to be really painful experience for me to implement caching logic with it.

Reading the docs regarding best practices help. For example, the default idea is that you define a RealmResults using an async query on the UI thread, add a change listener to it, and observe the latest emission of the database.

There is no "caching" involved in that beyond saving to the database and observing the database. Any additional complexity is added by you and is completely optional.

> All problems come from applying transaction to database which then must be synced on all threads working with Realm.

All looper threads automatically make the Realm auto-refresh, therefore if `addChangeListener` is used as intended in the docs, then there is no need for trickery, Realm will manage the synchronization between threads.

> I want to save my object to Realm and then query it out of.
>
> ```
> realm.executeTransactionAsync({
> ```

No reason to use `executeTransactionAsync` when you are already on a background thread.

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    realm.executeTransaction((r) -> {
         // do write here
    });
}
```

> ```
> realm.where(RealmChat::class.java)
> ```

If you do `import io.realm.kotlin.where`, then you can do `realm.where<RealmChat>()`.

> ```
> .findFirstAsync()
> ```

No reason to use `findFirstAsync()` instead of `findFirst()` when you are already on a background thread. Also no reason to use `load()` when you're on a background thread, because you should be using `findFirst()` in the first place anyway.

---

You are also most likely missing a `return@defer Single.just(chat)` to actually return the chat if it's found. That is most likely what your original problem is.

---

---

With the handler thread things you're doing though, you might want to consider taking a look at [this project called "Monarchy"](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy), as it intends to set up the ability to run queries on a background looper thread while still observing the results. It is labelled `stagnant` but the ideas are sound.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However ```return@defer Single.just(chat)``` is not the case, chat still doesn't get found. I tried to use sync transactions. I made a function to execute sync transactions https://www.codepile.net/pile/MYe4361q. And save chat like 
```rxSyncTransaction {it.insertOrUpdate(chat)}```. And it still did not help the situation

Comment: using ```findFirst()``` is also not helping

Comment: This is what led me to using these background threads and ```.isAutoRefresh```

Comment: Oh wait. I actuallly did use ```.findFirst()``` instead of ```.findFirstAsync()``` while still using this custom background scheduler and ```realm.isAutoRefresh = true``` and it actually worked!!! Holy shit! Thank you very much! I tried so many things to make it work and now it finally working.